# react with redux-saga: this.props.action is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

this is my store configuration:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const configureStore = () => {
    return {
        ...createStore(rootReducer,
            applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)),
        runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
    };
};

export default configureStore;
```

action:

```
export const getInvoicesAction = (payload) => ({
    type: types.GET_INVOICES_REQUEST,
    payload
});
```

and I am trying to mapDispatchToPtops in react component:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch=>{
    return {
        getInvoices: (query)=> dispatch(getInvoicesAction(query))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InvoicesPage);
```

and then calling function int componentDidMount:

```
export class InvoicesPage extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getInvoices('test');
    }
```

However in console it says, that `this.props.getInvoices is not a function`

Any solutions?

Comment: One little thing I can see from here is that save the state returned by createState in a variable and change the runSaga key on that variable and return that variable instead of using object spread since the runSaga of original store is not affected in your approach.

Comment: How are you importing `InvoicesPage` component to make use of it?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule import {InvoicePage} from './InvoicePage' and then <Route exact path='/' component={InvoicesPage}/>

Comment: @sudheersingh I tried to create store with this approach: `https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html` but nothing changed. error stayed the same

Comment: You should be importing the component connected with the store and actions which is the default export. `import InvoicePage from './InvoicePage'`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule wow that really worked. thanks man